# Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1

Tags: solidity

I am learning solidity and reviewed the voting example on the docs page.

I am modifying the example to become a contract where people vote on someone's good deed. And than the person gets karma points. See below. The "ballot" and "deed" functions are not working.

Probably a noob question but I get the error:

```
transact to Tasks.Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1
```

The error outputs the first letter I enter into the field to create a new "ballot" field when using Remix.

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;


contract Tasks {

    struct Person { // Person to do good deed
        uint weight; // weight is accumulated by delegation
        bool deedCompleted;  // if true, that person already completed a good deed
        address delegate; // person delegated to
        uint deed;   // index of the deedCompleted proposal
    }

    struct Proposal {
        bytes32 deedName;   
        uint karmaPoints;
    }

    address public chairperson;

    mapping(address => Person) public validators;

    Proposal[] public proposals;

    /// Create a new deed to choose one of `proposalNames`.
    function Ballot(bytes32[] proposalNames) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        validators[chairperson].weight = 1;

        // For each of the provided proposal names,
        // create a new proposal object and add it
        // to the end of the array.
        for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            // `Proposal({...})` creates a temporary
            // Proposal object and `proposals.push(...)`
            // appends it to the end of `proposals`.
            proposals.push(Proposal({
                deedName: proposalNames[i],
                karmaPoints: 0
            }));
        }
    }

    // Give `validator` the right to confirm deed was done
    // May only be called by `chairperson`.
    function giveRightToVote(address validator) public {
        require(
            msg.sender == chairperson,
            "Only chairperson can give right to deed."
        );
        require(
            !validators[validator].deedCompleted,
            "The validator already confirm deed was completed."
        );
        require(validators[validator].weight == 0);
        validators[validator].weight = 1;
    }

    /// Delegate your deed to the validator `to`.
    function delegate(address to) public {
        Person storage sender = validators[msg.sender];
        require(!sender.deedCompleted, "You already completed a deed.");

        require(to != msg.sender, "Self-delegation is disallowed.");

        while (validators[to].delegate != address(0)) {
            to = validators[to].delegate;

            require(to != msg.sender, "Found loop in delegation.");
        }

        sender.deedCompleted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Person storage delegate_ = validators[to];
        if (delegate_.deedCompleted) {
            // If the delegate completed deed,
            // directly add to the number of karmaPoints
            proposals[delegate_.deed].karmaPoints += sender.weight;
        } else {
            // If the delegate did not complete a deed yet,
            // add to her weight.
            delegate_.weight += sender.weight;
        }
    }

    /// Give your deed to a proposal
    function deed(uint proposal) public {
        Person storage sender = validators[msg.sender];
        require(!sender.deedCompleted, "Already deedCompleted.");
        sender.deedCompleted = true;
        sender.deed = proposal;

        // If `proposal` is out of the range of the array,
        // this will throw automatically and revert all
        // changes.
        proposals[proposal].karmaPoints += sender.weight;
    }

    /// Computes the winning proposal taking all
    /// previous validations into account.
    function completedProposal() public view
            returns (uint completedProposal_)
    {
        uint completedVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
            if (proposals[p].karmaPoints > completedVoteCount) {
                completedVoteCount = proposals[p].karmaPoints;
                completedProposal_ = p;
            }
        }
    }

    // Calls completedProposal() function to get the index
    // of the winner contained in the proposals array and then
    // returns the deedName of the winner
    function winnerName() public view
            returns (bytes32 winnerName_)
    {
        winnerName_ = proposals[completedProposal()].deedName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method ballot is expecting an array `function Ballot(bytes32[] proposalNames)` but you're providing a string.

Try to input an array at will work. example:

```
[ "prop 1" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The P is the first character of your argument, `Prop 1`.  Try wrapping it in double quotes, since it is expecting a bytes32

Comment: Double quotes renders the same error.

Comment: Ah, you need to quotes, but it also should be in an array.  ["<value>"]